# Unattended QGIS updates with OSGeo4W

Tags: qgis, installation, osgeo4w

I would like to do an unattended update of my QGIS install every night using windows task scheduler.

Is it possible to automatically update all installed packages with the OSGeo4W-Installer without user interaction?

I know that there are options like -k --autoaccept  and -q --quiet-mode and  -A --advanced but do I have to list all packages i want to upgrade or is it possible to get the same result as clicking through the advanced OSGeo4W-Setup where the installer automatically lists all updateble packages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You bet, since some great options were included from my old bug report and even more now.

https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ticket/351

You have to simply make sure that your scheduled task calls `osgeo4w-setup.exe` where on a 64-bit install would be in the default install directory at `C:\OSGeo4W64\bin` for 64-bit systems.

Include the options you've already mentioned and maybe some other ones like:

`osgeo4w-setup.exe -g -k -a x86_64 -q -A`

Where,

```
-g --upgrade-also [also upgrade installed packages]
-k --autoaccept [Accept all licenses]
-a --arch [architecture to install (x86_64 or x86)]
-q --quiet-mode [Unattended setup mode]
-A --advanced [Advanced install (as opposed to Express)]

# optional...
-o --delete-orphans [remove orphaned packages]
```

Comment: do you know if it is possible to define a postinstall batchfile that will be called after the installation is done?

Comment: @markgraeflerland I would maybe try to call the installation from your own batch file, which in turn would then call your postinstall file when it's done

Comment: good idea. sometimes you can't see the wood for the trees ;-)